# does installing ubuntu desktop modify existing installed packages?

Tags: installation, server, apt, virtualbox

I've setup an Ubuntu server using Virtualbox and Vagrant using these instructions: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/VAGRANT.md

I played around with the OS using the command line for a while and since I'm new to all things linux I decided to install the Ubuntu desktop using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
```

Before installing the desktop everything worked like it should from a command line. After installing the desktop gui it looks like things are missing or unable to be found. For example going to a command line and typing in "bundle install" results in the error `The program 'bundle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing ...`

Does installing a desktop gui on a ubuntu server screw around with existing installed files or did the "environment variables" get jacked with?

What files should I check to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did a `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` it would have listed the actions to be performed in terms of installing new packages, upgrading existing packages and removal of conflicting packages if applicable. Did you see anything in that to suspect removal?

Normally, installing 'ubuntu-desktop' metapackage shouldn't in any way affect something like 'bundle'. I don't know how the VM provided by discourse is setup. If it is using some thing like RVM (https://rvm.io) you might have to activate the settings of RVM into your shell before you can use the stuff installed within RVM.

Comment: The install scrolled by so fast and there was no way to scroll back up once it was done. Is the command 'bundle' apart of the Ubuntu OS or is this apart of ruby or some other program?

Comment: 'bundle' is a program that can be installed using your system's package manager `apt-get install bundler` in debian and its derivatives. But there is also something called 'gem' which works as a package manager for ruby modules/gems. So a `gem install bundler` could also be used to install bundler. Normally installing stuff on system-wide ruby is not such a good idea. So people use stuff like RVM (https://rvm.io) to create isolated ruby environments and install the ruby gems inside that using `gem install` command

Comment: @StrandedPirate In the future, do `apt-get --dry-run install ubuntu-desktop | less` to scroll over the list of modifications without applying them.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the following to the .bashrc file in my home directory. This modifies the environment **PATH** variable for all consoles to include the bin directory for ruby. There's probably more paths needed as well to fix `bundler` and others.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin
```